# using math.pow in the middle of a function

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Financial program and i need to use math.pow to take (1 + (rate)^term). It doesn't like my formatting but i don't know how to write it in a way that it would like it. 
Here's the full loop that i'm making it in:

```
static void doPV()
    {
        double Famount, rate, pv;
        int term;

        Famount = getValue("Amount to be recieved in the future? ");
        rate = getValue("Annual Interest rate (6.5% = 6.5): ");
        while (rate < 1 || rate > 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rate must be between 1% and 25%");
            rate = getValue("annual Interest rate (6.5% = 6.5): ");
        }
        term = getTerm();

        pv = 0;
            for(int i=1; i<= term; i++)
        {
            double intearn = (pv = Famount / Math.Pow(1 + (rate / 100.0 / 12.0)), term);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Famount.ToString("C") +
                          " recieved in " + term.ToString() +
                          " months discounted at an annual rate of " +
                          (rate / 100).ToString("P") + " has a value today of: " +
                          pv.ToString("C"));
    }
```

Comment: "*It doesn't like my formatting*" is not an error message nor a technical description of a problem

Comment: `recieved` - incorrect spelling

Comment: In the text of the question, you wrote (1 + (rate)^term), which is the same as 1 + (rate^term).  But your code is trying to do (1+rate)^term, which is different from that text.  Which do you want?  (The answer from @Gekctek correctly points out a parentheses problem, but keeps this logic discrepancy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just incorrect placement of parentheses. This should work instead:

```
double intearn = pv = Famount / Math.Pow(1 + (rate / 100.0 / 12.0), term);
```

I find it helpful to break statements like this into a couple lines for readability

Comment: Thanks you're right it works just fine. I thought i needed it there so it the double would read properly. thank you so much for the help. i feel silly with it being something as simple as that.